# How do you upgrade Azure Devops 2022 RC1 to 2022.1?

Tags: azure-devops

Do you start with the full upgrade and run through the same steps as a full upgrade?

Ex: run azuredevops2022.1.exe

Is there a patch?  I found devops2022.1patch1.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to upgrade from Azure DevOps 2022 RC1 to 2022.1, you can run the `azuredevops2022.1.exe` to perform a full upgrade.

According to the [Azure DevOps Server 2022 Update 1 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2022u1?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 is a roll up of bug fixes. It includes all features in the Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 RC2 previously released. The `devops2022.1patch1.exe` is a released Patch 1 for Azure DevOps Server 2022 Update 1.

So, after you run the `azuredevops2022.1.exe`, you can run the `devops2022.1patch1.exe` to update the patch.